# Singleton from Dagger Hilt doesn't found in JetpackCompose project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I was developing an App where I try to make some practices with Jetpack Compose, and I've tried to added Dagger Hilt as dependency injector too.

My problems comes, when I try to make use of @Singleton annotation is doesn'tfound, although the other clases of Dagger libraries works fine.

My project build gradle is the following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my module app build.gradle is this:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'kotlin-android'
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
....

dependecies{
...

      // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.0.0"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"

    //Inject and Singleton
    implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"

...

}
```

Finally the picture which show the error I get when I try to use @Singleton is this:

[image]

So what Am I missing?? Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: try to remove `implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"`

Comment: At the begining I haven't that dependency and doesn't work either. In fact, if you do it, Android Studio request to use SDK 11 instead of SDK 1.8 as is setted. Thanks for your comment !